Get macOS audio volume not rounded
Essentially, I want to get the exact audio output volume in macOS without any rounding to an integer.
I am already aware that I can execute the following to get an output volume:
osascript -e "output volume of (get volume settings)"

However, the problem with this volume is that it is very evidently rounded to the nearest integer.
This can be proven using the knowledge that each increment of volume on macOS is 1/16 = 0.0625 = 6.25%.
Output of above command given the number of bars highlighted starting from a volume of 0:



Number of bars
Expected volume
Command output




0
0.00
0


1
6.25
6


2
12.50
13


3
18.75
19


4
25.00
25


5
31.25
31


6
37.50
38


...
...
...



This table is quite indicative that the volume is not an integer but is being rounded when outputted through osascript.
As such, is there any way I can retrieve the actual macOS volume with the fractional/decimal component included? It doesn't have to be using built-in methods. I would be happy to consider the use of libraries like Python's pyobjc, too.

Did you consider using a lookup table to map the integer values to the actual numbers?

@nohillside This would work if I was just trying to limit the volume retrieval to the bars set when using the macOS volume up and down buttons. However, the macOS volume can be set to a volume in between the bars, which I require for my purposes.

Update: With a little help from OpenAI, I've written a tool in Swift that should provide a solution. The source code and precompiled binary releases are up on GitHub:
luckman212/volctl
It can list, get and set the volume levels of your audio devices with high precision. It also supports muting/unmuting. I've tested this only on macOS 15.1.x, but I believe it should run on older releases without issue.
Example usage
$ volctl list
118 In/Out  ZoomAudioDevice
125 Input   Logitech Webcam C925e
129 Input   RODE NT-USB
142 Output  DELL S2721QS
85  Output  External Headphones
79  Output  Mac mini Speakers
134 Output  RODE NT-USB

$ volctl set 85 0.2109

$ volctl get 85
0.2109

$ volctl mute 79


(note that the native MIDI app rounds to 3 decimal places when displaying the volume level)
Another open-source tool mentioned in my previous answer is karaggeorge/macos-audio-devices.
It provides a CLI as well as a library that can be imported into other apps. This program's set method allows a precise floating point value, such as 0.383 (confirmed by inspecting the value in Audio MIDI Setup.app) However, the value is rounded to 2 decimals when using the get method.

Hi, @luckman212. Just tested this now. A couple notes: 1) The command is actually audio-devices after installation rather than the name of the full npm package. 2) The retrieved volume is the same as the output of osascript -e "output volume of (get volume settings)" but divided by 100. It isn't any more precise at all unfortunately.

@GigiBayte2 On my system, both macos-audio-devices and audio-devices are symlinks to the same binary. Sorry this solution didn't end up being what you needed.

Hi, @luckman212. Yes, this is my experience with the methods I have been using as well. You can set volume with a fair bit of precision, but retrieving it is always constrained as mentioned unfortunately.

Works great! Thank you.

Just realized I hadn't awarded the bounty. My bad!
